# How to extract 2 strings into indivitual arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, replace, strtok

The goal of this program is to replace given words in redact string into asterisks in a full sentence.

e.g. given a full sentence: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
and redact string: "the, jumps, lazy", the output is "*** quick brown fox ***** over *** **** dog", which needs to be saved in a result.txt.

My main idea is to first extract redact string and a full sentence into an array before searching for a word. If it matches, the array of full sentence is replaced with asterisks. Finally, an array is converted back to a string.

The problem of my code is that I want to extract string from fullSentence[] and redactString[] into individual arrays but when I run this code it output...

The
jumps,
lazy
the
Y├╠╠╠╠╠╠j

This is the code:

```
int main(void) {

    char fullSentence[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    int t = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char **redactArray = NULL;
    char *token = strtok(fullSentence, " ");


    char redactString[] = "the, jumps, lazy";
    int j = 0;
    char *p = strtok (redactString, ", ");
    char *extractString[3];


    for (t = 1; token; ++t) { // Extract fullSentence[]
        redactArray = realloc(redactArray, t *sizeof(*redactArray));       
        redactArray[t - 1] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strncpy(redactArray[t - 1], token, strlen(token) + 1);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < t-1; ++i){
        printf("%s\n", redactArray[i]);
    }


    while (p != NULL) { // Extract redactString[]
        extractString[j++] = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    }

    for (j = 0; j < sizeof(extractString); ++j) {
        printf("%s\n", extractString[j]);
    }

    return extractString;
}
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` Why doesn't the delimiter include a comma? Please show your exact run log.

Comment: You can't call `strtok(redactString, ", ")` until after your loop that gets the tokens from `fullSentence`. `strtok(NULL, ...)` tokenizes the last string that you used without `NULL`.

Comment: You could also use `strtok_r()`, which has an explicit argument that holds the state of the tokenization, rather than continuing the last one.

Comment: @kaylum I used space as a delimeter to extract individual word into an array from full sentence "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char fullSentence[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    char **fullArray = NULL;    // tokenized array for fullSentence
    int m = 0;                  // array length of fullArray

    char redactString[] = "the, jumps, lazy";
    char **redactArray = NULL;  // tokenized array for redactString
    int n = 0;                  // array length of redactArray

    char *token;
    int i, j, k;

    for (token = strtok(fullSentence, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        fullArray = realloc(fullArray, (m + 1) * sizeof(*fullArray));
        fullArray[m] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strncpy(fullArray[m], token, strlen(token) + 1);
        m++;
    }

    for (token = strtok(redactString, ", "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, ", ")) {
        redactArray = realloc(redactArray, (n + 1) * sizeof(*redactArray));
        redactArray[n] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strncpy(redactArray[n], token, strlen(token) + 1);
        n++;
    }

    // compare the words one by one ignoring case
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (strcasecmp(fullArray[i], redactArray[j]) == 0) {
                // the words match. redact the word in fullArray[i]
                for (k = 0; k < strlen(fullArray[i]); k++) {
                    fullArray[i][k] = '*';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // print the redacted string
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("%s%s", fullArray[i], i == m - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*** quick brown fox ***** over *** **** dog
```